# TextToSpeech stops working after a few hours

Tags: android, sockets, text-to-speech

I'm trying to make an app reading a string coming from a socket connection, but after a few hours the app stops talking (without exceptions). I'm sure the app is still running because the server sending the string continues to detect the response echo after sending it.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


TextToSpeech textToSpeech;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            if(status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.ITALY);
            }
        }
    });

    Thread socketT = new Thread(new SocketThread());
    socketT.start();

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if (textToSpeech != null) {
        textToSpeech.stop();
        textToSpeech.shutdown();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}


private class SocketThread extends Thread {

    static final int socketPort = 3333;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(socketPort);
            try {
                while(true) {
                    Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                    try {
                        new ServerThread(clientSocket);
                    } catch(IOException e) {
                        clientSocket.close();
                    } }
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
            }
            serverSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    class ServerThread extends Thread {
        private int counter = 0;
        private int id = ++counter;
        private Socket socket;
        private BufferedReader in;
        private PrintWriter out;
        public ServerThread(Socket s) throws IOException {
            socket = s;
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
            out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(osw), true);
            start();
        }
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    String str = in.readLine();
                    textToSpeech.speak(str, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {}
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch(IOException e) {}
        }
    }


}



}
```

Answer (score 0):

`TextToSpeech` instance will be available after connect to system service, not after invoke constructor.

So, your plan need to edit like this:

1. Call `TextToSpeech` constructor.
2. Check your `TextToSpeech` instance is finish to connect to system service through `TextToSpeech.OnInitListener.onInit()`.
3. Then, connect to your custom service.

Try this as below:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            if(status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                int res = textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.ITALY);
                if (res >= TextToSpeech.LANG_AVAILABLE) {
                    // TextToSpeech instance is available after connect to system service!
                    Thread socketT = new Thread(new SocketThread());
                    socketT.start();
                }
            }
        }
    });

    // At this time, your TextToSpeech instance may be not available yet.
    //Thread socketT = new Thread(new SocketThread());
    //socketT.start();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try and I will let you know.
But this does not explain why it initially works and then stops working after a few hours

Comment: Well, I agree about that. For more precise analysis, I need to know Android debug logs. Could you update logcat contents?

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem persists.
When I start the application on the emulator, tts always works while on an android box it stops working after a while so I can't retrieve a log, I will try to install an app that for the logs

Comment: TextToSpeech: speak failed: TTS engine connection not fully set up
TextToSpeech: speak failed: not bound to TTS engine

These are the error messages. I noticed that it does not stop working after a few hours, but it stops working randomly.

Comment: That means `TextToSpeech` instance is failed to connect to TTS service on your device.